# Расскажите, что делает нижеприведённая функция. Для чего она может быть использована? Напишите пример использования

Tags: javascript

```
function bind(method, context) {
 var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
 return function() {
  var a = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0));
  return method.apply(context, a);
 }
}
```

Comment: А почему вы копипастите задания из учебника или экзаменационный билет? Нормальный, живой человек никогда не напишет так.

Comment: @VladD это вариант написания своего bind. Выглядит как вполне рабочий код, разве что название переменной "a" является неудобным для восприятия. Может использоваться, как я писал в ответе ниже, в древних браузерах (когда этой функции вообще нет), либо когда надо расширить функционал встроенных функций (либо нет к ним доверия и используется самописная библиотека).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Кросс-браузерная эмуляция bind](https://learn.javascript.ru/bind#%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-bind)

Функции в JavaScript никак не привязаны к своему контексту this, с одной стороны, здорово – это позволяет быть максимально гибкими, одалживать методы и так далее.

Но с другой стороны – в некоторых случаях контекст может быть потерян. То есть мы вроде как вызываем метод объекта, а на самом деле он получает this = undefined.

В результате вызова bind(func, context) мы получаем «функцию-обёртку», которая прозрачно передаёт вызов в func, с теми же аргументами, но фиксированным контекстом context.

Аналог bind для IE8- и старых версий других браузеров будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
function bind(func, context /*, args*/) {
  var bindArgs = [].slice.call(arguments, 2); // (1)
  function wrapper() {                        // (2)
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var unshiftArgs = bindArgs.concat(args);  // (3)
    return func.apply(context, unshiftArgs);  // (4)
  }
  return wrapper;
}
```

Работает так (по строкам):

1. Вызов bind сохраняет дополнительные аргументы args (они идут со 2-го
   номера) в массив bindArgs.
2. … и возвращает обертку wrapper.
3. Эта обёртка делает из arguments массив args и затем, используя метод
   concat, прибавляет их к аргументам bindArgs (карринг).
4. Затем передаёт вызов func с контекстом и общим массивом аргументов.